# Magento 2 : Create Custom Product Tab and Populate it With Product Attributes

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.2, tabs

What would be a straight forward solution for creating a custom block as a product tab and populate it with product attributes?

Comment: You are looking for admin? Means you need yo create new section while product add or edit with your custom attribute?

Comment: Well admin would be awesome, but I think this would require code. I am talking about the tabs that are in the product pages, that have information from attributes. But I want to create a custom tab, that has information about selected attributes .